# How can i get list of font family(or Name of Font) in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

How can i get list of font family(or Name of Font) in matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.font_manager
matplotlib.font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=None, fontext='ttf')
```

With help of this code i can get only directory of font.
How can i get list of Font-Name like

> "Century Schoolbook L", "Ubuntu".... etc

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try following:

```
>>> import matplotlib.font_manager
>>> [f.name for f in matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.ttflist]
['cmb10', 'cmex10', 'STIXNonUnicode', 'STIXNonUnicode', 'STIXSizeThreeSym', 'STIXSizeTwoSym', 'cmtt10', 'STIXGeneral', 'STIXSizeThreeSym', 'STIXSizeFiveSym', 'STIXSizeOneSym', 'STIXGeneral', 'cmr10', 'STIXSizeTwoSym', ...]
>>> [f.name for f in matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.afmlist]
['Helvetica', 'ITC Zapf Chancery', 'Palatino', 'Utopia', 'Helvetica', 'Helvetica', 'ITC Bookman', 'Courier', 'Helvetica', 'Times', 'Courier', 'Helvetica', 'Utopia', 'New Century Schoolbook', ...]
```

Comment: It might render _a lot_ of duplicates, adding `set()` will give you the unique fonts ordered apathetically. So,

`set([f.name for f in matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.afmlist])`

and

`set([f.name for f in matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.ttflist])`

Comment: @MartVandeVen, Thank you for your comment. FYI, in Python 2.7, set comprehension is also available. `{f.name for f in matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.afmlist}`. Also you can use generator expression instead of list comprehension (to avoid creating intermediate list object).